# Singleton EXC_BAD_ACCESS

Tags: objective-c

so I have a class that I declare as a singleton and in that class I have a NSMutableArray that contains some NSDictionaries with some key/value pairs in them. The trouble is it doesn't work and I don't know why... I mean it  crashes with EXC_BAD_ACCESS but i don't know where. I followed  the code and it did create a new array on first add, made it to the end of the function ..and crashed ...

```
    @interface dataBase : NSObject {
    NSMutableArray *inregistrari;

}

@property (nonatomic,retain) NSMutableArray *inregistrari;



-(void)adaugaInregistrareCuData:(NSDate *)data siValoare:(NSNumber *)suma caVenit:(BOOL)venit cuDetaliu:(NSString *)detaliu;
-(NSDictionary *)raportIntreData:(NSDate *)dataInitiala siData:(NSDate *)dataFinala;
-(NSArray *)luniDisponibileIntreData:(NSDate *)dataInitiala siData:(NSDate *)dataFinala;
-(NSArray *)aniDisponibiliIntreData:(NSDate *)dataInitiala siData:(NSDate *)dataFinala;
-(NSArray *)vectorDateIntreData:(NSDate *)dataI siData:(NSDate *)dataF;
-(void)salveazaInFisier;
-(void)incarcaDinFisier;
+ (dataBase *)shareddataBase;


@end
```

And here is the .m file

```
#import "dataBase.h"
#import "SynthesizeSingleton.h"


@implementation dataBase
@synthesize inregistrari;


SYNTHESIZE_SINGLETON_FOR_CLASS(dataBase);


-(void)adaugaInregistrareCuData:(NSDate *)data siValoare:(NSNumber *)suma caVenit:(BOOL)venit cuDetaliu:(NSString *)detaliu{
    NSNumber *v=[NSNumber numberWithBool:venit];
    NSArray *input=[NSArray arrayWithObjects:data,suma,v,detaliu,nil];
    NSArray *keys=[NSArray arrayWithObjects:@"data",@"suma",@"venit",@"detaliu",nil];

    NSDictionary *inreg=[NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjects:input forKeys:keys];

    if(inregistrari == nil) {
        inregistrari=[[NSMutableArray alloc ] initWithObjects:inreg,nil];
    }else {
        [inregistrari addObject:inreg];
    }


    [inreg release];
    [input release];
    [keys release];

}
```

It made it to the end of that adaugaInregistrareCuData ... ok . said the array had one object ... and then crashed

Answer (score 3):

Try adding "NSZombieEnabled" with value "YES" to your arguments on your executeable:

Right click your executeable, select get info and add that entry to the variables in the bottom list.

This will tell you what datatype has crashed.

Using build & analyze it tells me that you are releasing **inreg, input and keys** twice.

All three variables will be autoreleased, your manual release will cause the later autorelease to fail and give you your BAD_ACCESS.

Don't manually release them, remove these three lines from your code:

```
[inreg release];
[input release];
[keys release];
```

Comment: Current language:  auto; currently objective-c
(gdb) continue
2010-05-22 22:18:59.829 Licenta[2954:207] *** -[CFArray release]: message sent to deallocated instance 0x3b62c70
(gdb) 

This is what I get with the NSZOmbieEnabled ... so it's a CFArray.. 
wtf is a CFArray ?

Comment: Tried whitout the release as you recommended.. still same error.

Comment: __forwarding__
--forwarding-0
nspopautoreleasepool
uiapplicationhandleevent
purpleeventcallback
cfrunlooprunspecific
cfrunloopruninmode
gseventrunmodal
gseventrun
uiaplicationmain
main

yep .. smt to do with the autorelease pool

Comment: CFArray is the simple data type NSArrays are based on. Try "Build and analyze" from the menu "Build > Build and analyze". Walk thru the comments it is giving you, it should give you a very good direction where your problems are. When it isn't given you any feedback, do you still have access problems?

Comment: Well now I have another problem. the array defined inside the singleton disappears for no reason , and i cant use it in cellForRow atIndexPath .. . nothing is dealocated .. it is used once .. then when the screens moves a little it's just gone